# Postgresql Replica is in sync but repmgr says node unattached

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6, repmgr

I've set up a replica of a Postgresql instance using repmgr, and the replica is totally in sync with the master instance and have been in sync since some days, but `repmgr` tells me replica isn't connected.
This is what the cluster looks like:

```
postgres@www:~$ repmgr cluster show
 ID | Name             | Role    | Status    | Upstream    | Location | Connection string
----+------------------+---------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | orig_master      | primary | * running |             | default  | host=MASTER user=USER dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
 2  | orig_slave       | standby |   running | orig_master | default  | host=SLAVE user=USER dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
```

This is what we get on the replica instance:

```
postgres@db:~$ repmgr node status
Node "orig_slave":
    PostgreSQL version: 9.6.11
    Total data size: 5603 MB
    Conninfo: host=SLAVE user=USER dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
    Role: standby
    WAL archiving: disabled (on standbys "archive_mode" must be set to "always" to be effective)
    Archive command: rsync -a %p barman@BARMAN:/mnt/volume/prod/incoming/%f
    WALs pending archiving: 0 pending files
    Replication connections: 0 (of maximal 6)
    Replication slots: disabled
    Upstream node: orig_master (ID: 1)
    Replication lag: 0 seconds
    Last received LSN: 63/BB0E3C10
    Last replayed LSN: 63/BB0E3C10
```

Which clearly shows that we have no relpication lag and instances are in sync, and WAL numbers are correct too.
This is what I get on the master instance:

```
postgres@www:~$ repmgr node status
Node "orig_master":
    PostgreSQL version: 9.6.11
    Total data size: 5603 MB
    Conninfo: host=MASTER user=USER dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
    Role: primary
    WAL archiving: enabled
    Archive command: rsync -a %p barman@BARMAN:/mnt/volume/prod/incoming/%f
    WALs pending archiving: 0 pending files
    Replication connections: 1 (of maximal 6)
    Replication slots: disabled
    Replication lag: n/a

WARNING: following issue(s) were detected:
  - 1 of 1 downstream nodes not attached:
    - orig_slave (ID: 2)

HINT: execute "repmgr node check" for more details
```

Which tells me that downstream node isn't connected, which is clearly connected!
Now, my question is: Is there actually a problem in replication process? If yes, then What is it and how can I solve it? If not, how can I make `repmgr` sure that there is no problem?

P.S.: Postgresql 9.6.11, repmgr 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try running the following command from the standby node:

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf standby follow
```

The paths of the `repmgr` file and the `repmgr.conf` configuration file may vary according to the installation.